# Excel offset function for multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to use excel offset function to build a dynamic chart. Basically, I want my line chart always show the data for last 5 days. I know how to do it for a single variable, but for multiple variables, I have no idea. 
Can you help me？

My data is in below format. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Rvvv.png)

[image]

In the chart, there should be four dynamic lines--area1 vol, are2 vol, area3 vol, and the total vol.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide the expected output for the sample data. Better in a table form than a graph.

Comment: You may be able to use Aggregate instead. Where is the source data?

Comment: what do you mean by source? just excel data.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming **Date** is in A1 then,

```
=index(A:I, match(today()-4, A:A, 0), 0):index(A:I, match(today(), A:A, 0), 0)
```

Avoid the volatile OFFSET whenever possible; it usually can be done.

Comment: seemly, you have selected all the range, not just the colume B, D, F, and G. I can not put the rang into the chart using "select data".